# Using relational operators for several fields in django model filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a requirement to find a unique record depending on two date fields and a char field as follows.

```
Start Date
End Date
Item No. (There will be unique item numbers.)
Owner ID - This is what should be retrieved from the model.
```

**Provided: Data model is implemented such a way, within the Start and End dates Item can only be possessed by one owner.**

> Requirement: When the Item No. and a Date is given, find the owner of
>   the item within that day.

Assume that this is stored in the model named **Ownership**.
Model has following fields to store the start, end dates and item no.

```
Ownership.start_date
Ownership.end_date
Ownership.item_no
```

A user submit values for Item and Date in a form which are stored in variables user_date, user_item_no.

I know this should be using filter logic as follows. But how can I refer those fields in my query? (negative scenarios will be discarded)

Filter:

```
(user_date >= Ownership.start_date) AND (user_date <= Ownership.end_date)
 AND (Ownership.item_no = user_item_no)
```

Note: When building the filter query I have to refer the model's fields in the filter itself (*within ()*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want something like this

```
ownerships = Ownership.objects.filter(start_date__lte=user_date, end_date__gte=user_date, item_no = user_item_no)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I need.